# Have to change tabs in order to HTML appear properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, jquery-events, jcarousel

I have used jCarousel to create what? A carousel. Then, the boss wanted me to create some selectors so that the user could select different lists of the results (as if it were the same carousel, but showing different results).

The strategy I used was simple: I created multiple carousels and hide them. Only the selected carousel will appear.

It works fine except for one thing: In Firefox (and now in IE8) I am forced to change to another tab of the browser and then get back or change the window size if I want to to see it the it should.

Of course, this is not the kind of thing that a user guesses or even tolerates.

### EDIT

Here's what I am trying to achieve:
[image: Second tab selected]
[image: First tab selected]

Here's what is wrong:
[image: The problem]
**This is the appearance of the list when it is first loaded and before the window is re-sized or I select some other tab in the browser**

When I change tabs in the browser or change the size of the window, it starts working correctly.

I believe that if I call and an handler for an event (like resize window, tabchanged or something like that). What do you think?

### More data

: I am not sure if this will be relevant to the case, but I am using jCarousel. The element that an incorrect width is the corresponding unordered list that contains the elements that you see in the images above.

Comment: Can you please explain a little more about what's going wrong?  Your language is a little unclear.  Thanks :)

Comment: @Surreal Dreams, if you  need more detail, I'll be glad to explain. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code solved the problem:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).resize();
</script>
```

Hope this helps someone in a far far far way future.

Comment: On Safari and Chrome I needed to execute this code only after every element was loaded using $(document).load(function() { /* Same code... */ });

Answer (score 0):

what if you try a page refresh and tie

Comment: What do you mean by tie? I understand the word but not in this context. A page refresh by itself is not something that I can force the user to do, but refreshing the page will not do the trick. Thanks.

Comment: I added more detail and images to the question. Thanks for your help, @user466764.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies the answer submitted before I could finish. I meant to say tie a page refresh to the script such as top.location.href - not sure of the jquery equivalent.

Comment: I solved the problem by triggering the resize event, but thanks anyway!